# Возможно ли для пользователя увидеть исходный PHP-код сайта?

Tags: php, безопасность

Допустим, Вы создаёте свой сайт, сосотоящий из PHP-страниц, которые содержат HTML-код. Эти страницы находятся в корневой папке на хостинге (там же, где и главная `index.php`).  Понятно, что пользователь, если откроет в браузере средства разработчика, увидит лишь сгенерированный HTML-код.

Вопрос: возможно ли для пользователя при таком раскладе увидеть исходный PHP-код, не взламывая сервер с целью получить доступа к файлам? В частности, прошу Вас упомянуть в ответе программы для сохранения страниц с целью дальнейшего их просмотра с автономном-режиме.

Comment: эти программы действуют ровно так же, как и браузер, и магией не обладают. пока сервер не отдает напрямую содержимео файлов, все безопасно

Comment: Такая возможность есть, но только если по каким-либо причинам упал PHP, а Apache продолжает работать. Хз как это можно гарантированно воспроизвести (это будет самый крутой способ взлома, если научиться воспроизводить), но сам уже несколько раз видел, как сайты падая выдают исходный код, вместо процессинга PHP. Так что, к сожалению, приведенные ответы не совсем верны.

Answer (score 11):

Это невозможно ровно до тех пор, пока вы случайно не выключите парсинг PHP-кода в .php-файлах.

Тем не менее, обратившись к файлам, к которым пользователь не должен обращаться, он потенциально так или иначе может навредить вам или даже узнать информацию, которую ему не следует знать. Поэтому рекомендуется делать так, чтобы в директории, доступной по HTTP, был всего 1 PHP-файл: `index.php`. Этот файл в свою очередь должен уже взаимодействовать с другими PHP-файлами, находящимися уровнем выше этого каталога. Примерно так:

```
project/
├── public/
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── robots.txt
│   └── sitemap.xml
└── app/
    ├── MyClass.php
    └── MyAnotherClass.php
```

Вы сможете обратиться к `index.php`, скажем, по адресу `localhost/index.php`, равно как к `localhost/robots.txt` и `localhost/sitemap.xml`, но обратиться к файлам `MyClass.php` и `MyAnotherClass.php` по HTTP вы никак не сможете.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! ...так значит мы будем программными средствами любую страницу сайта генерировать в `index.php`? Тут у меня сразу же возникло много вопросов. Динамическую смену контента сделать можно, а вот как быть с навигационным меню, которое рекомендуется делать из ссылок? Мы же будем ссылаться на другие страницы из этого меню.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, пока вы на начальной стадии изучения PHP, пишите так, как вам удобно и понятно. Затем, когда поднаберетесь знаний, процесс рефакторинга (это когда старый код заменяется более "правильным", соответствующим вашему текущему уровню) начнется сам собой и вы столкнетесь с такими понятиями, как [ЧПУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL) и роутинг. И вместо `localhost/registration.php` ваши ссылки будут выглядеть как `localhost/registration` с одним-единственным `index.php` в публичной директории.

Comment: Понял. Ну а если речь идёт о создании сайтов на заказ, то допустимо делать так, как я сейчас делаю? (по php-файлу на каждую ключевую страницу)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, нет. Вы должны нести ответственность за код, который пишете не для себя, а он подвержен "нежданчикам" со всех щелей. Также, если подобный код попытается прочесть другой программист, то у него явно будет плохой день. Если хочется побыстрее начать делать простейшие сайты на заказ, подтягивайте PHP и прыгайте с головой в фреймворк [CodeIgniter 3](http://www.codeigniter.com/). Там и документация хорошая, да и сам он простой в освоении.

Comment: Как всегда, какая-то чушь про "навредить или даже узнать". Если веб-сайту можно навредить, просто обратившись к пхп файлу, то переставлять местами пхп файлы - это, конечно, именно то что надо делать.

Answer (score 1):

php код работает на сервере. он отдаёт вашему браузеру страницу как вы её видите. Т.е. к клиенту летит результат работы пхп-файла в виде скомпилированного html. Не сам файл. То о чём вы спрашиваете возможно только по фтп, если через браузер.