# PHP: простейший пример перехода на другую страницу без добавления нового файла сверх index.php

Tags: php

В одном из комментариев на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591989/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) узнал о том, что делать отдельный php-файл под каждую страницу сверх `index.php` - технически неправильно. Тогда вопрос: а как сделать, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу удалялось прежнее содержимое и появлялось новое, если мы находимся в одном и том же `index.php`?

Да, я понимаю, для этого пишут специальные классы для роутинга, но я хочу начать с чего-нибудь простого, что я понимаю, как оно работает, а потом уже усложнять это. Поэтому в данном вопросе я прошу показать такой пример: при нажатии на пункт меню "Другая страница" мы должны остаться в `index.php`, но надпись "Это главная" должна исчезнуть, а вместо неё - появиться что-то другое - это будет иммитация перехода на другую страницу с помощью навигационного меню. Естественно, я прошу сделать это на чистом `PHP` без `JavaScript`.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <!-- неверно -->
    <!-- <li><a href="/other_page.php">Другая страница</a></li> -->
</ul>

<div> Это главная </div>
```

Comment: Смысл не в том, чтобы засунуть все страницы в index.php. Как раз наоборот - в index.php вообще ничего не будет ни про какие страницы, только роутинг, который вызывает нужную функцию, а внутри этой функции уже генерируется страница. Тот подход, который вы представляете, намного хуже подхода "каждой странице по файлу".

Comment: Ну хорошо, вот мы роутинг вызвал какую-нибудь функцию, и у нас сгенерировался HTML-код. Теперь мы ходим перейти на другую страницу, а значит роутинг снова должен вызвать нужную функцию. Что эта функция делает-то? Перезагружает страницу, убирает выходной HTML-код и подставляет новое содержимое? Почему я сказал "перезагружает страницу", а не "уходит с неё", потому что мы как были в файле index.pnp, так и остаёмся в нём.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что то, что вы описываете - это два разных вызова файла index.php с разными параметрами? Скрипт, как только отдаст страницу, сразу же прекратит свою работу, вы никак не можете в нём остаться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите оставаться на индекс странице, и при этом должен получиться эффект перехода на другие страницы, тогда для идентификации других страниц ипользуйте параметр $page:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
   <li><a href="/?page=another_page">Другая страница</a></li>       
   ...
</ul>
```

В самом коде скрипта вы разделяете содержимое по условию:

```
<?php
  ...
  if($_GET['page'] == 'another_page'){

     Вывод содержимого другой страницы  

  } else {

     Вывод содержимого индекс страницы 

  }
```

При этом у вас получится эффект многостраничности. Само содержимое страниц можно разбить на html файлы и подгружать их через file_get_contents(), или же разместить в файлах php и включать с помощью include:

```
<?php
 ...
 if($_GET['page'] == 'another_page'){

   include_once 'include/another_page_content.inc.php';

 }
```

Comment: Отлично, это как раз то, что я хотел увидеть! Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Answer (score 5):

Каждый раз, когда вы переходите по ссылке, страница заново загружается с сервера. Даже если фактически сервер обрабатывает все с помощью одного и того-же php-файла. Разделите в своем сознании URL адрес и физический адрес файла — эти вещи не связаны между собой, хотя так кажется.

Такой модуль как `mod_rewrite` переадресовывает запросы с разных URL адресов на один файл, как будто этот файл действительно находится по этому адресу. Это может быть что угодно: `index.php`, `notindex.php`, `engine/core/rewrite/lib/start.php` — любой файл может отвечать на запрос `http://site/news/all`, если так настроен `mod_rewrite`

Например, когда к серверу общаются по адресу `http://site/foo/bar` можно настроить `mod_rewrite` так, что это запрос пойдет к другому файлу, а *url* пойдет в качестве переменной: `http://site/startpoint.php?url=foo/bar`

Получив адрес страницы в виде переменной GET, можно определить, какой заголовок и контент страницы нужно выводить