# Стоит ли стремиться убрать имя скрипта отправки данных формы из HTML-кода для повышения безопасности?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Допустим, я не хочу, чтобы в HTML-коде формы авторизации содержалось имя скрипта проверки данных таким образом:

```
<from name="authForm" method="post" action="checkAuthData.php">
```

Говорят, что при взломе злоумышленники не заполняют формы, а напрямую отправляют данные на скрипт (подробностей не знаю). Вопрос: если мы заменим имя скрипта на PHP-функцию, то это позволит исключить взлом подобным образом? (Нам понадобится подключить в файл PHP-скрипт через `require`, но ведь этого не должно быть ввидно в выходном HTML-коде).

Кстати, о подключении функции вместо имени скрипта. Видел [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit) решение, но судя по тому, что у него нет плюсов, оно едва ли будет работать:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="display()">
<input type="text" name="studentname">
<input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
<?php
function display()
{
echo "hello".$_POST["studentname"];
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
       display();
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Если так, про наверняка можно вызвать PHP-функцию через AJAX без указания файла скрипта в JS-коде.

Ещё раз повторюсь, что смысл всего этого - убрать из выходного HTML-кода, который любой может посмотреть с помощью инструментов разработчика в браузере, если это повысит безопасность.

Comment: так уже сто лет в обед никто не делает. Все в современном мире используют маршрутизацию (routing) и ссылки получаются типа `/users/` или `posts/15` ......а на сервере уже правила разруливаются........ напрямую названия скриптов не пишут уж лет нацать

Answer (score 4):

В современной разработке на PHP принято использовать роутинг. Если простыми словами, то роутинг - это такая штука, которая позволит вам создавать совершенно разную логику в зависимости от того, с помощью какого HTTP-метода пользователь обратился к вашей странице.

Допустим, есть у нас страница авторизации по адресу `/auth` (обратите внимание на то, что окончания `.php` тут нет, но об этом позже). Если мы обратимся к этому адресу по методу GET, то мы получим обычную форму авторизации. Но магия роутинга заключается в том, что мы можем обратиться к этому же адресу и по методу POST, например, через AJAX-запрос, который будет происходить при отправке формы авторизации, а страница будет отвечать JSON-объектом.

Роутинг подразумевает использование ЧПУ (человекопонятные URL). То бишь вместо `/news.php` адреса ваших страниц должны выглядеть как `/news`. Важно понимать, что при реализации роутинга и ЧПУ вы должны не просто обрезать окончание `.php`, а строить целую внутреннюю карту сайта (роутинг по-русски можно обозвать словом "маршрутизация"). То есть в зависимости от адреса обращения и HTTP-метода вы выбираете скрипт(ы), которые будут выполнены. Такой подход позволяет вам скрыть исходные имена PHP-файлов и обезопасить их от прямых обращений. Это имеет смысл только в том случае, если в публичной директории у вас доступен только один PHP-файл - `index.php`, который является точкой входа во всю логику вашего сайта. Подробнее о том, что это такое и зачем нужно, я писал в ответе на этот вопрос: [Возможно ли для пользователя увидеть исходный PHP-код сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591989/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/591992#591992)

Все, что я назвал выше, чаще всего используют с парадигмой MVC (Model, View, Controller). Это такая магия, которая позволяет вам отделять логику скрипта от его представления. Таким образом у вас логика и HTML-разметка почти не пересекаются. В модели находится логика, контроллер лишь перебрасывает данные из модели во вью, а вью содержит уже HTML-разметку и простейшую логику шаблонов (if и циклы).

Вы можете с ужасом прочитать всё, что я написал, и ничего не понять. Потому что это довольно обширная тема, достойная серии статей, которую я пересказал вкратце своими словами. Но именно такой подход позволит вам достичь не только нормальной степени безопасности, но и поддерживать такой проект будет в тысячи раз проще. На самом деле, разумнее прибегнуть к использованию PHP-фреймворков в своих проектах, где всё это (и даже больше) реализовано из коробки. Для новичков идеальным выбором будет какой-нибудь [CodeIgniter 3](http://www.codeigniter.com/), в котором минимум излишнего функционала и отличная документация. Просто перейдите на любой фреймворк и большинство вопросов о безопасности и лучших практиках сами исчезнут.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Читал не с ужасом, ибо обо всём этом уже слышал. Но как реализуется sumbmit-отправка в MVC?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, ну, в принципе, как обычная отправка формы через AJAX. Попробуйте CodeIgniter 3. Там вводный гайд хороший, равно как и документация по фичам. Попробуйте все возможности своего сайта переписать под него. Все кодят на фреймворках, так что вам все равно рано или поздно придется столкнуться с ними.

Comment: какой еще пример простенького популярного фреймфорка?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, честно говоря, из простых я только с CI3 работал. Двух-трех месяцев изучения мне хватило, чтобы понять, как и что должно работать, а затем почти безболезненно перешел на уже серьезный и сложный Laravel 5.

Answer (score 2):

Имя файла-обработчика Вы не сможете скрыть, если хотите чтобы браузер о нём знал.
А о чём знает браузер, знает и злой хакер.

Да и смысл защищать имя файла, как это хоть как-то поможет защитится?

Защищайте лучше логику скрипта.

---

Вызов `PHP`-функции из JS - это сильно. Нереально, но сильно :)