# Как правильно отдавать коды ошибок HTTP?

Tags: php, apache, http

Прописал я в .htaccess собственные страницы ошибок сайта, пока для двух наиболее распространённых из них:

```
ErrorDocument 403 "/error/403/"
ErrorDocument 404 "/error/404/"
```

И обнаружил, что Апач просто загружает указанные файлы, "как есть", то есть не только показывает их пользователю, но и отдаёт скриптам, например, если неверно прописан путь к таблице стилей, причём с кодом 200. Благо код поменять недолго:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
```

и

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

соответственно. Но как быть с телом страницы? Очевидно, что скриптам сайта и сторонним программам - поисковым роботам, RSS-агрегаторам, приложениям, подключённым к API сайта т.д. - достаточно получить код ошибки, но можно ли как-то отдавать им только его, а пользователю, открывающему страницу в браузере, - документ целиком? И каким способом лучше всего различать автоматические и ручные обращения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И обнаружил, что Апач просто загружает указанные файлы, "как есть", то есть не только показывает их пользователю, но и отдаёт скриптам, например, если неверно прописан путь к таблице стилей, причём с кодом 200

Если я правильно понял, вы говорите о том, что если указывается нерабочая ссылка на какой-нибудь ассет (скрипты, таблицы стилей), то ваш сервер пытается отдать HTML-документ. Самое очевидное решение проблемы - это просто следить за тем, чтобы ссылки были всегда валидны. Зачастую одной таблицы стилей и одного JS-файла достаточно для целого сайта. А если использовать шаблонизацию, то достаточно будет указать путь к ассетам лишь в одном файле и не бояться, что где-то что-то сломается.

Но в любом случае имеет смысл использовать роутинг и MVC. Начнете использовать эти две техники - и подобные проблемы решатся сами собой. Никто уже не использует .htaccess для обработки ошибок.

Кажется мне, что вы не используете фреймворки в уже почти 2017 году, где подобные проблемы решены из коробки. Советую почитать мои ответы, где я затрагивал подобные темы и объяснял, почему вы **должны** использовать единую точку входа в приложение, MVC, роутинг и, возможно, фреймворки:

- [Стоит ли стремиться убрать имя скрипта отправки данных формы из HTML-кода для повышения безопасности?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607557/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-html-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE/607562)
- [Возможно ли для пользователя увидеть исходный PHP-код сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591989/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/591992)

> Очевидно, что скриптам сайта и сторонним программам - поисковым роботам, RSS-агрегаторам, приложениям, подключённым к API сайта т.д. - достаточно получить код ошибки, но можно ли как-то отдавать им только его, а пользователю, открывающему страницу в браузере, - документ целиком?

В этой идее нет смысла. Если поисковик получает однозначный код ответа (например, Forbidden или Not Found), то ему уже будет плевать, как выглядит тело страницы. Спустя какое-то время он ее просто исключит из индексации.

Действовать следует примерно так:

- API-запросам - отдавать JSON-объект с ошибкой и описанием ошибки (например, "API endpoint not found").
- Всем остальным - какое-нибудь красивое сообщение о том, что страница не найдена.

Во всех случаях следует отдавать валидный HTTP-код: 403 или 404.

> И каким способом лучше всего различать автоматические и ручные обращения?

По юзер-агентам. У каждого робота этот заголовок свой.

Comment: MVC я использую, и вообще стараюсь повторять при разработке сетевых приложений структуру проекта Rails, пусть и слегка видоизменённую, с безопасностью тоже всё ок: из сети доступны только API и индексный файл. А вот про роутинг по методам запроса забыл, спасибо, что напомнили. Фреймворки не использую, так как предпочитаю, чтобы приложение делало то, что нужно **мне**, а не то, что считает нужным разработчик фреймворка - возни с Рельсами и их бесконечной сменой версий, без обратной совместимости, хватило.

Comment: @Risto, ну, в отличие от CMS, фреймворки вас не вгоняют в какие-то рамки и ни в чем не ограничивают, особенно это касается профессиональных фреймворков (Laravel, например). При разработке хорошего проекта вы в любом случае будете стремиться повторить функционал, который большинство фреймворков будут предоставлять из коробки, только вот у них этот функционал будет богаче, отлаженнее (покрыт тестами) и задокументирован. Действительно весомых причин отказываться от них нет. Все опытные разработчики используют их, используйте и вы.