# Ограничение доступа к скриптам напрямую средствами php

Tags: php, include, доступ

Пытаюсь постигнуть моменты безопасности.

Подскажите, есть ли какие-то рецепты запретить запуск скриптов php напрямую запросом из браузера?

Читал вариант про задание константы, например, в index.php и потом её проверке во всех include-файлах. А можно ли как-то ограничить доступ к тем, что не инклудятся?

Или вообще это плохая идея и делается иначе?

Comment: Да, это делается иначе. Смотрите мой ответ на вопрос, где я объяснил, как в современных проектах на PHP защищаются от произвольного вызова PHP-файлов: "[Возможно ли для пользователя увидеть исходный PHP-код сайта?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/591989/212210)". Я бы мог просто скопировать ответ, но не думаю, что так делать правильно.

Comment: Я запрещаю прямой доступ через .htaccess